# Composite keys in a Multi-tenant database

Tags: database, security, multi-tenant

I'm designing a database for pure multi-tenancy (one database, one schema) and I'd like to keep a Tenant_Id in most of my tables as a security measure to ensure that data doesn't fall into the wrong tenant's hands.  It seems like this would require a composite key on every table.

Example:

Under single-tenant circumstances, I would have a single primary key:

```
Animal_Id (PK)  
Animal_Type  
Animal_Name
```

Under Multi-tenant circumstances, I would add another primary key for Tenant_Id:

```
Animal_Id (PK)  
Tenant_Id (PK)  
Animal_Type  
Animal_Name
```

Does adding a Tenant_Id column to every table mean that I will need to have a composite key in every table, or is there a secure way to avoid this?  Composite keys are ok, but I'd like to avoid them if I can.

Comment: You said, "I'd like to keep a Tenant_Id in most of my tables as a security measure to ensure that data doesn't fall into the wrong tenant's hands." How do you expect a tenant_id column to prevent data from falling into the wrong tenant's hands?

Comment: @Catcall: by filtering on `tenant_id`?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Only works if you never, for the life of the database, have more than one tenant per unit. Odds are not good.

Comment: @Catcall: the goal of multi-tenant database is to have one tenant per unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your ids are autoincremented integers, you can add `tenant_id` which is not a part of the primary key and just check for it in all your queries.

However, this has several side effects which you may or may not see as drawbacks:

- You can possibly link two entities from different tenants in a many-to-many link table and the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint won't prevent you from doing this (as it would in case `tenant_id` were a part of the `PRIMARY KEY`)
- Your users can evaluate how many other tenants are there from the ids
- You will have to additionally join the entity tables to the searches which could possibly be done only from many-to-many link tables (to check the tenant)

In other words, if you really don't like composite keys for entities, it is possible to design the database without them.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are repeating the other id per customer (you could have two or more animal_id = 1) there is no real reason to make it a composite key. You can just add the field.  That's works for us.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to support two different tenants having the same `ANIMAL_ID` value?  Whatever mechanism you're using to generate what appear to be synthetic primary key values should be able to generate values that are unique across tenants.  Adding a `TENANT_ID` column to the table would potentially make sense but it's not obvious that adding it to the primary key would be beneficial.

Comment: Cool.  Maybe I'm over-complicating things.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Why dont we add GUID as identifier for each record? instead of auto incremented id

Comment: @Murali - That is certainly an option.  In general, though, generating a GUID is slower than getting the `nextval` from a sequence and requires more space to store the data.  It can also make it more challenging to support the system-- it is easy enough to tell someone to look at `ANIMAL_ID` 4227 if you're tracking down an issue in the data.  It is harder to send along a 32 character hexadecimal representation of a 16 byte RAW value and ensure that someone else is looking at the correct row.

Comment: Thanks Justin!. Can you look my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911357/managing-tenant-specific-master-record-in-shared-database and if possible add your suggestions? Your input is always useful